# Programmatically assign a role to a scope in Microsoft AzMan?

Tags: windows-server-2003, rbac, mmc, azman

I'm using `AzMan` on Windows Server 2003, and I've written a management application that completely hides `AzMan` and the `MMC` from the security team.
However, I'm having a hard time implementing one of the features in the `MMC`.

I have a role called `User`, and a role called `Branch User` which contains nothing but the `User` role. I want to assign the `User` role at the all data (`Role Assignments`) level, and the `Branch User` role at the scope level.
However, I can't find a way to programmatically assign the `Branch User` role to a scope without it losing its definition. I can assign the role (by calling `CreateRole` on the scope) but it seems to just create a new blank role. When I right click it in the `MMC`, click on properties, and then ***Show Definition***, it doesn't have anything.

Also, if I try to then call `AddTask` on that `IAzRole` object to add `User` to it, it doesn't quite work as expected. It will add all the tasks in the `User` role to my `Branch User` role, but not the role itself.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So I just had an "oh duh" moment. I programmatically call CreateRole("Branch User", null) and then on that IAzRole object, call AddTask("Branch User", null) and it does what I want. I'm still experimenting to see if there are any undesirable side effects to this... I'm not sure if it's the right way, but it kind of makes sense now that I think about it with the AzMan model. Anyone know for sure if this is how I'm supposed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on WIN2k3 that is the correct way. Unfortunately in AzMan versions **before Vista/Win2k8**, a role definition is a `Task` with the `task.IsRoleDefinition` set to `1`. It has it's own well named class in newer versions.

Basically `CreateRole()` is creating a `Role Assignment`, not a `Role Definition` (this doesn't necessarily need to have the name `Branch User`, it could be anything). A Role Assignment contains the links between definitions of roles/tasks/operations and members/users.

You are then adding the Role `Branch User` to the `Role Assignment` using `app.AddTask()`.

To do this only for a particular ***Scope*** you need to call `app.OpenScope` (or `app.CreateScope`, if new) which returns an `IAzScope` object.  You can then do all the above on `scope.CreateTask` or `scope.CreateRole`.